# WinForms & Infragistics controls readonly property does not work for clicked control

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics

I wrote this code to make all controls readonly.

```
makeReadOnly(Control control, bool bIsReadOnly)
{
   for(int i=0; i< control.Controls.Count; i++)
   {
        if(control.Controls[i].Controls.Count > 0)
        {
           makeReadOnly(control.Controls[i], bIsReadOnly);
        }
        else if(control.Controls[i].GetType() == typeof(UltraTextEditor))
        {
           (control.Controls[i] as UltraTextEditor).ReadOnly = bIsReadOnly;
        }
        else if(control.Controls[i].GetType() == typeof(UltraNumericEditor))
        {
           (control.Controls[i] as UltraNumericEditor).ReadOnly = bIsReadOnly;
        }
        else if(control.Controls[i].GetType() == typeof(ListBox))
        {
           (control.Controls[i] as ListBox).Enable = !bIsReadOnly;
        }
   }
}
```

It works but if user clicks one control such as a textbox, then click edit button(call makeReadOnly function). Function does not work for the clicked textbox. (It works for the other controls only).

```
Private void EditButton_Click()
{
     foreach(Controls control in this.controls)
     {
          makeReadOnly(control, false);
     }
}
```

"this" represents parent form."EditButton_Click()" is button event.
Why it is not working for the clicked ones?
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Not sure to have understood correctly. You have a UltraTextEditor with some buttons added to the ButtonsLeft or ButtonsRight collection and you want them to not be active when you set the UltraTextEditor to ReadOnly state?

Comment: edit button is a  general form button to open all fields and initialize dropdown lists etc.

Comment: Could you show the code that calls this method?

Comment: I think, I found the answer. Problem is Infragistic. When user cliked an UltraTextEditor or UltraComboEditor. Infragistic changes its type to something like "EmbeddableUIText..." and its parent type become UltraTextEditor or UltraComboEditor. So, I have to check this types or controls' parent types to solve it.
(my rep is less than 10 so now I can't answer my own question :-/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I found the answer. The problem is in Infragistics controls. When a user clicks an UltraTextEditor or UltraComboEditor controls, Infragistics changes its type to something like "EmbeddableUIText..." and its parent type becomes UltraTextEditor or UltraComboEditor. So, I have to check this types or controls' parent types to solve it.